# not getting slash / on my website url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

**My .htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>


#non www redirection 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^ruggedtrailsnepal\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://ruggedtrailsnepal.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

i am not getting / (slash) on some url , but some url's are  working  , how to solve this problem

link with problem

```
ruggedtrailsnepal.comtravel-info/visa-information.html
```

link without problem

```
ruggedtrailsnepal.com/company-info/about-us.html
```

Comment: What is the `!` for in the `!^ruggedtrailsnepal\.com`? Second to the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Reorder your rules and use `REQUEST_URI` variable:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    #non www redirection 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^ruggedtrailsnepal\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://ruggedtrailsnepal.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Better test this in a new browser to avoid old caches.